# Prevent firefox from resetting scroll position when overflow element changes

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, modal-dialog

I am trying to implement a modal popup like the way facebook does it for previewing photos.  From what I've inspected, the body becomes overflow:hidden and the modal box becomes overflow-y:scroll.

However, I have a bug in my website for firefox where when I change the overflow element from auto to hidden, it resets the scroll position of the page.  This does not happen in Chrome.  Any workaround/fix for this?  Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for your help. Please look at the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k3evQ/7/.

Greatly appreciate it!!!

Comment: Can you provide a link or a fiddle to show this? Doesn't sound right. In this fiddle you can see that mousing over red does not reset scroll position - http://jsfiddle.net/k3evQ/1

Comment: Yeah... an example with source code is definitely needed. Also, have you tried some modal plugins? http://goo.gl/iqf76 (Tip: Reveal by ZURB is great and easy to customize for @media queries, if needed)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I revised your jsfiddle.  Basically I would put a modal popup inside the bigger modal box so that it would have a faded background.  http://jsfiddle.net/k3evQ/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up scrapping the idea of changing the overflow to hidden.  Thanks for all your help anyway.